# How do I write hexadeximal floating point literal in java?

Tags: java, literals

For number `-5 x 10^-1` i.e., `-0.5`, I could write,

`-5E-1f` or `-50E-2f` or `-0.05E+1F`

as "decimal floating point literal" in java.

If the same number is written in "hexadecimal floating literal", I found it as

`-0X32p-2f` which is wrong. This value is `-25.0`. I considered `50` as `0x32` and came out with this notation.

How do I learn writing the above value `-5 x 10^-1` in hexadecimal floating point literal?

Comment: `50E-2f` means `50 * 10^-2`.  `0x32p-2f` means `0x32 * 16^-2` (where ^ means "to the power of" here).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it's not `16^-2`, it's `2^-2`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `0x32 * 16^-2` goes to `0.19`, but `java.exe`  shows as `0.25`

Comment: @Jesper: Ah, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [section 3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) of the Java Language Specification:

In case of a hexadecimal floating point literal, the exponent is a **binary** exponent; it's a power of 2, not a power of 10 as in decimal floating point literals.

So `0x32p-2f` means 50 times **2** to the power -2, not times 10 to the power -2.

A hexadecimal `float` literal that represents `0.5` would be `0x1p-1f`.

Comment: I rely on people who read JLS and speak on video. I cannot read JLS now. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the documentation for [`Double.toHexString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString(double)).